# Applying the fadeIn to a slide fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fullpage.js

I'm having trouble applying a fadeIn and function to the .intro section of a slide. I've configured it to the sections I want but can't seem to apply it to the slide 1. I'm very new to writing html and the like.

This is the css I've written:

```
 #section1 .intro{
     display:none;
}

 #slide1 .intro{
     display:none;
}
```

This is the javascript I've added:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex){

                //section 1
                if(index == 2){
                    //moving the image
                    $('#section1').find('.intro').first().fadeIn(800, function(){
                        $('#section1').find('.intro').last().fadeIn(800);
                    });;
                }

                //section 2
                if(slideIndex == 1){
                    //moving the image

                    $('#slide1').find('.intro').first().fadeIn(800, function(){
                        $('#slide1').find('.intro').last().fadeIn(800);
                    });;
                }
```

This is the html for the slides I want to apply the effect to:

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <div class="intro">
            <h2>Header</h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="slide2">
        <img src="Images/image.svg">
    </div>
    </div>
```

I did also attempt to apply a fadeOut transition, so that as a viewer left the section it, would fade out so that next time that section was viewed the fade in transition would happen again. But this was my pretty hopeless attempt at it:

```
afterLeave: function(anchorLink, index){

                //section 1
                if(index == 2){
                    //moving the image
                    $('#section1').find('.intro').first().fadeOut(800, function(){
                        $('#section1').find('.intro').last().fadeOut(800);
                    });;
                }
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to use .active not #section1 -> $('.active').fadeOut(); $('.active').next().fadeIn(); make a fiddle from this and i sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

`afterLoad` [according to the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) has only two parameters and you are using 3:

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},
```

`onLeave` [according to the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction) has 3 parameters and you are using 2:

```
 onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){},
```

Also, note that you are not using `onLeave`, you are using `afterLeave`, which doesn't exist.